# Temporarily exit the MySQL command line to shell (bash)

Tags: mysql, bash

Is it possible to temporarily exit from MySQL command line to shell (bash) and then get back to MySQL CLI again? In Vim it is possible with the help of `:sh` command and `^-D` to get back to Vim. I'm interested if the same is possible in MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `system` (or, short, `\!`) [`MySQL client command`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-commands.html) to execute an external shell command.

If you want to spawn a shell then try:

```
system bash;
```

or, shorter:

```
\! bash;
```

When `bash` ends (with `exit` or `Ctrl-D`) the control gets back to the `mysql` client program.

---

Use the `help` command to see all MySQL client commands.

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly what I need.